# RabbitMQ gives a "access refused, login refused for user" error when attempting to follow the celery tutorial

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, amqp, celery

I'm attempting to follow the [celery tutorial](http://ask.github.com/celery/introduction.html#usage), but I run into a problem when I run `python manage.py celeryd`: my RabbitMQ server (installed on a virtual machine on my dev box) won't let my user login.

I get the following on my Django management console:

```
[ERROR/MainProcess] AMQP Listener: Connection Error: Socket closed. Trying again in 2 seconds...
```

and this shows up in my `rabbit.log` file on my RabbitMQ server:

```
exception on TCP connection <0.5814.0> from $DJANGO_BOX_IP
{channel0_error,starting,{amqp,access_refused,"login refused for user '$CONFIGURED_USER'",'connection.start_ok'}}
```

I've double-checked my user, permissions, and vhost info, and they all seem to match up. Any help troubleshooting is greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: Following the advice of @asksol I get the following traceback:

```
$MY_VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/python2.6/site-packages/carrot/connection.pyc in connection(self)
    118             return
    119         if not self._connection:
--> 120             self._connection = self._establish_connection()
    121             self._closed = False
    122         return self._connection

$MY_VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/python2.6/site-packages/carrot/connection.pyc in _establish_connection(self)
    131 
    132     def _establish_connection(self):
--> 133         return self.create_backend().establish_connection()
    134 
    135     def get_backend_cls(self):

$MY_VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/python2.6/site-packages/carrot/backends/pyamqplib.pyc in establish_connection(self)
    110                                insist=conninfo.insist,
    111                                ssl=conninfo.ssl,
--> 112                                connect_timeout=conninfo.connect_timeout)
    113 
    114     def close_connection(self, connection):

$MY_VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/python2.6/site-packages/amqplib/client_0_8/connection.pyc in __init__(self, host, userid, password, login_method, login_response, virtual_host, locale, client_properties, ssl, insist, connect_timeout, **kwargs)
    138                 self.wait(allowed_methods=[
    139                     (10, 20), # secure
--> 140                     (10, 30), # tune
    141                     ])
    142 

$MY_VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/python2.6/site-packages/amqplib/client_0_8/abstract_channel.pyc in wait(self, allowed_methods)
     88         method_sig, args, content = self.connection._wait_method(
---> 89             self.channel_id, allowed_methods)
     90 
     91         if content \

$MY_VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/python2.6/site-packages/amqplib/client_0_8/connection.pyc in _wait_method(self, channel_id, allowed_methods)
    196         while True:
    197             channel, method_sig, args, content = \
--> 198                 self.method_reader.read_method()
    199 
    200             if (channel == channel_id) \

$MY_VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/python2.6/site-packages/amqplib/client_0_8/method_framing.pyc in read_method(self)
    213         m = self.queue.get()
    214         if isinstance(m, Exception):
--> 215             raise m
    216         return m
    217 

IOError: Socket closed
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you running django?
If so, then try this:

```
>>> from carrot.connection import DjangoBrokerConnection
>>> c = DjangoBrokerConnection()
>>> c.connection
```

Does it give the same thing?
Are you sure you're connecting to the right hostname, and that the username and password has access to the virtual host?

UPDATE:

```
>>> from carrot.connection import DjangoBrokerConnection
>>> c = DjangoBrokerConnection()
>>> for n in ("host", "userid", "password", "virtual_host", "ssl"):
...     print("%s -> %s" % (n, repr(getattr(c, n, None))))
```

UPDATE: You have to do the above before running c.connection, as the connection is established lazily in carrot.

Comment: I am running Django. Doing the above from the Django shell gives me a fairly long traceback and results in the following error: `IOError: Socket closed`. I'll update the question with the traceback.

Comment: Ok, There must be something in the configuration that is wrong, host, vhost, permissions, username, password and so on. See updates to my answer for more troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks. The login info was wrong: I got my virtualhost value in the setting for the password.